# How to add video duration to youtube v3 api native android

Tags: android, youtube

am working on youtube player using youtube v3 api. I tried to add video duration using part=ContentDetails to my video search request, but it keeps returning error for contentDetails/duration. Does anybody have any means of getting around this problem. Here is my search request Url code below.

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?contentDetailsorder=viewCount&q=;&type=video&maxResults=14&part=snippet,&fields=items(id/videoId,snippet/title,snippet/thumbnails,contentDetails/duration)&key= Constants.YOUTUBE_API_KEY;

Answer (score 1):

The [Search:List](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) call does not return the duration of a video in its search results. All the fields available can be seen [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search#resource).

In order to get the duration of the videos call [Videos:List](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) with the `id` field set to a comma delimited list of the `videoId`s that you get from the search call. For instance:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=contentDetails&id=RgKAFK5djSk%2Cw1oM3kQpXRo&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

you can then access contentDetails\Duration for each of the videos.